# Match the elements of a vector and a matrix, returning a new matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following numpy arrays:

```py
[
  [96.6074, 73.3443, 37.2574],
  [11.2753, 39.8242, 42.1898],
  [46.5815, 76.2492, 71.7398],
  [4.99222, 7.64707, 6.5171],
]
```

```py
[
  True,
  False,
  False,
  True
]
```

Now I want the elements of the boolean array to correspond to the rows of the float array.
I want to "match" them and create 2 new arrays, where:

- `arr1` will contain only the rows of floatArray where the same rows (by index) in boolArray had **`True`**
- `arr2` will contain only the rows of floatArray where the same rows (by index) in boolArray had **`False`**

I'm think it can be done with a loop like this:

```py
arr1 = np.array([])
arr2 = np.array([])

for idx, element in  np.ndenumerate(boolArray):
    if (element == True):
        # append floatArray[idx] to arr1
    else:
        # append floatArray[idx] to arr2
```

But I'm new to python and I'm not really sure how to do it.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use array masking:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([
        [96.6074, 73.3443, 37.2574],
        [11.2753, 39.8242, 42.1898],
        [46.5815, 76.2492, 71.7398],
        [4.99222, 7.64707, 6.5171],
    ])
>>> mask = np.array([True, False, False, True])
>>> arr[mask]
array([[96.6074 , 73.3443 , 37.2574 ],
       [ 4.99222,  7.64707,  6.5171 ]])
>>> arr[~mask]
array([[11.2753, 39.8242, 42.1898],
       [46.5815, 76.2492, 71.7398]])
```

Comment: Woah, that's exactly what I needed... Thanks! I was sure there was a built-in way to do this!